# nav button size changing in different browsers

Tags: html, css, border, gradient, nav

I'm trying to make a navbar with a gradient and top and bottom borders. Trying it on different browsers results in slightly different sizes which break the layout by 1px. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the HTML:

```
<head>
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
</header>
<div id="navbar" class="gradient">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 1</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 4</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 5</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 6</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 7</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #222;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

header {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

h1 {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 968px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Times", "Times New Roman", "serif";
    font-style: italic;
}

#navbar {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 31px;

    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 14px;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 14px;

    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 968px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    /* width: 138px;*/
    display: inline;
    padding: 6px 0;
    float: left;

    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

li:hover {
    background: #ededed; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%, #f6f6f6 53%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ededed), color-stop(53%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#f6f6f6 53%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#f6f6f6 53%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#f6f6f6 53%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ededed 0%,#f6f6f6 53%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be completely honest, welcome to the wonderful world of Web Development. I would suggest creating a separate CSS file for each browser (Or at least IE), that way you can tweak the CSS to conform to your vision.

Get your Navbar looking good in say, Firefox/Chrome, then move on to tweaking a separate style-sheet for use with IE.

For example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ieisterrible.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that **CSS 3 gradients won't behave equally in different browsers**. You may generate a gradient using **[Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)** which generates gradient for cross browser support. Even then, you can notice some color and behavior changes according to browser. In this case, I *strongly* recommend you to;

- Make a nav-bar like rectangle in some image editor like Photoshop.
- After applying the gradient, you may re-size the width to `1 px` (height is not a problem)
- You may then apply this image to your navbar using CSS like

  `background: #color_code gradient_image repeat-x`
- Since the image is just 1px wide, the size will be less and will load comparatively faster.